# ext4: Splitting and Concatenating File in situ

Tags: file, split, concatenation, ext4

Say I have a large file on a large disk and this file fills the disk almost entirely. e.g. 10TB disk, almost 10TB file, say 3GB are free. Also, I do not have any other

I would like to split that file in N pieces, but splitting in half is ok for simple case. As the desired solution is probably FS specific, I'm on an ext4 filesystem.

I am aware of https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#split-invocation

Obviously, I do not have enough free space on the device to create the splits by copying.

Would it be possible to split file A (~10TB) into two files B and C in a way, so these (B and C) would simply be new "references" to the original data of file A.

I.e. B having the same start (A_start = B_start), but a smaller length and C, starting at B_start+B_length having C_length = A_length-B_length.

File A might or might not exist in the FS after the operation.
Also, I'd be fine if there was some constraint/restriction like this was only possible at some sector/block boundary (i.e. only 4096 byte raster).

Same question applies to the inverse situation:

Having two files of almost 5TB each on a 10TB hard disk: concatenating these to a resulting file of nearly 10TB size by merely adjusting the "inode references".

Sorry if the nomenclature is not that precise, I hope it's clear what I try to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is currently no guaranteed portable way to do what you want - any solution is going to be platform-specific, because to do what you want requires that your underlying filesystem support sparse files.

Code like this will work to split a file in half if the underlying filesystem creates sparse files (proper headers and error checking left out for clarity):

```
// 1MB chunks (use a power of two)
#define CHUNKSIZE ( 1024L * 1024L )
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int origFD = open( argv[ 1 ], O_RDWR );
    int newFD = open( argv[ 2 ], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644 );

    // get the size of the input file
    struct stat sb;
    fstat( origFD, &sb );

    // get a CHUNKSIZE-aligned offset near the middle of the file
    off_t startOffset = ( sb.st_size / 2L ) & ~( CHUNKSIZE - 1L );

    // get the largest CHUNKSIZE-aligned offset in the file
    off_t readOffset = sb.st_size & ~( CHUNKSIZE - 1L );

    // might have to malloc() if it doesn't fit on the stack
    char *ioBuffer[ CHUNKSIZE ];

    while ( readOffset >= startOffset )
    {
        // write the data to the end of the file - the underlying
        // filesystem had better create a sparse file or this can
        // fill up the disk on the first pwrite() call
        ssize_t bytesRead = pread(
            origFD, ioBuffer, CHUNKSIZE, readOffset );

        ssize_t bytesWritten = pwrite(
            newFD, ioBuffer, byteRead, readOffset - startOffset );

        // cut the end off the input file - this had better free up
        // disk space
        ftruncate( origFD, readOffset );
        readOffset -= CHUNKSIZE;
    }

    free( ioBuffer );
    close( origFD );
    close( newFD );
    return( 0 );
}
```

There are other approaches, too. On a Solaris system, you can [use `fcntl()` with the `F_FREESPC` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1463/fcntl-2.html) and on a Linux system that supports the `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` you can use [the fallocate() function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) to remove arbitrary blocks from the file after you've copied the data to another file. On such systems you wouldn't be limited only being able to cut the end off the original file with `ftruncate()`.